# Web api not bringing back data

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, python-requests

I am currently using python requests to consume a web api written in c# within my MVC application.  This is the error I get

```
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.</h2>
  <h3>The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
```

and here is the python code I am using

```
constURLString = "http://10.1.30.15/test/api/DevicesAPI"
send = requests.put(constURLString + "/" + str(deviceID), data = urlParam)
```

urlParam is the model I am passing back to the webapi in order to edit that specific entry. I tried typing the actual url into my browser trying to get that single entry by typing http://10.1.30.15/test/api/DevicesAPI/16 and got

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message></Error>
```

Which isn't very helpful.  This seems to work perfectly when I am running it locally but doesn't seem to like it when I publish it to the server. My put method within my web api goes as is:

```
// PUT: api/DevicesAPI/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutDevices(long id, Devices devices)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != devices.deviceID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(devices).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!DevicesExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an error code other than "An error has occurred."? Such as a 500 or 404?

Comment: @SamuelDavidson I edited the error code I get from my SSH client, Firebug console also tells me that I get a 500 error

Comment: are you missing the port number  in url ? 

http://10.1.30.15:PORT/test/api/DevicesAPI/16

Comment: Could you give more of the error? It is difficult to figure out where and why the error is occurring without more information.

Comment: Samuel "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://10.1.30.15/test/api/DevicesAPI/16" That's all I get from firebug, when I take off the id at the end, it seems to get all the entries fine

Comment: So an error 500 usually means that an uncaught exception was thrown during your action. Assuming your action is being called correctly and all your parameters are valid, it seems the issue may be with your database. I have had issues with databases once pushing my application onto servers. The body of the Error 500 HTTP response should contain some exception information to help you figure out your problem. If you are having trouble reading the body within Python, try downloading and using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to test.

Comment: I have found out why I am getting a 500 error, this was actually 2 problems, one in which I have resolved by removing the webDAV module and webdav from handler mappings. @SamuelDavidson I am getting 500 error because I have 2 actions which have the same route signature.  I will update my post to accommodate this